# class to connect java program to database(which accepts parameters)

Tags: java, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write a class that will accept two strings and an int (username and password and score) from a quizgame, which eventually will come from a GUI, at the minute I'm just passing them through from the main, and pass them into a database to be inserted.

I have the JConnector jar file added and am working in Eclipse.

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

//public 
class DbConnect {

    private java.sql.Connection con;
    private java.sql.Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DbConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/nostalgic", "root", "usbw");

            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error is " + ex);
        }

    }

    public void setData(String n, String p, int x) {
        try {

            String query = "select * from nostalgic";
            String query1 = "INSERT INTO nostalgic values (n,p,x)";

            PreparedStatement statement3 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
            statement3.executeUpdate();

            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("records from database");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String name1 = rs.getString("name");
                String pw = rs.getString("password");
                int score = rs.getInt("score");
                System.out.println("Name : " + name1);
                System.out.println("Password : " + pw);
                System.out.println("Score : " + score);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }

    }
}
```

The error I get is

> Unknown column 'n' in 'field list'

I can directly put a string in like 'john' but that is no use to me in this situation.

Comment: You are doing good; regarding that this is your first question. But please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: @kai pls just don´t do this rather use `"INSERT INTO nostalgic values (?,?,?)"` and use the `setString(pos, value)` and `setInt(pos, value)` methods

Comment: You are not using anywhere classes from `com.mysql.jdbc` package so don't import them. change these imports to `java.sql` package.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `INSERT INTO nostalgic values (n,p,x)` you should have 
`INSERT INTO nostalgic values (?,?,?)` and then:

```
PreparedStatement statement3 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
statement3.setString(1,n);
statement3.setString(2,p);
statement3.setString(3,x);
statement3.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

in

```
String query1 = "INSERT INTO nostalgic values (n,p,x)";
```

n,p,x are not being replaced with the values, they are just being considered as some char that's why you get this error

Edit : before `statement3.executeUpdate();`

```
        String query1 = "INSERT INTO nostalgic values (?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement statement3 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
        statement3.setString(1,n);
        statement3.setString(2,p);
        statement3.setInt(3,x);
```

**Update:** you may wonder why `Unknown column 'n' in 'field list'`?
Because as insert query in sql  can have this structure

```
  INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,...) values (`val1`,`val2`,....)
```

but then values need to be inside ``` `` ``` if hard coded so if there is no ``` `` ``` sign they are considered as column name.

Answer (score 0):

Mick,
the problem is that you don't pass actual parameters to your query when doing  `statement3.executeUpdate();`. Check this link to see how to do it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like that try this:

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/nostalgic","root","usbw") {
                PreparedStatement pr = null;
                String query = "INSERT INTO nostalgic VALUES ((?), (?), (?))";
                pr = con.prepareStatement(query);
                pr.setString(1, n);
                pr.setString(2, p);
                pr.setString(3, x);
                int status = pr.executeUpdate();
           }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code...

- Correct imports
- Insert statement

Your code will be like that:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.jdbc.Statement;
// you imported sql innecessary statements...    


//public 
class DbConnect {

    // dont need complete path, you already imported it  
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DbConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/nostalgic", "root", "usbw");

            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error is " + ex);
        }

    }

    public void setData(String n, String p, int x) {
        try {

            String query = "select * from nostalgic";

            String query1 = "INSERT INTO nostalgic values (?,?,?)";
            // no need to define vars here, 
            // just number of places to be inserted here ----^ 

            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query1);
            // prepare statement
            statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            // insert the variables in places you prepared before
            // and matching the types you need!!!
            statement.setString(1,n);
            statement.setString(2,p);
            statement.setInt(3,x);    
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("records from database");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String name1 = rs.getString("name");
                String pw = rs.getString("password");
                int score = rs.getInt("score");
                System.out.println("Name : " + name1);
                System.out.println("Password : " + pw);
                System.out.println("Score : " + score);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }

    }
}
```